# Hide Parent of Div

Tags: javascript, parent

I'm simply trying to hide the parent div `comments_section`.

```
<div class="content content_green">
    <div id="comments_section"></div>
</div>
```

I tried this:

```
document.getElementById("comments_section").parentNode.style.display = "none"
```

which worked, but gives me this error in IE 9:

> Unable to get value of the property 'parentNode': object is null or underfined.

I'm very new to JavaScript, so I'm not sure how to fix this error or if it's even the right approach. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you tagged this jQuery so I'll provide the "jQuery way":

```
jQuery('#comments_section').parent().hide();
```

EDIT: @bobek gives the reason why your problem occurred in the first place. He is correct. I should note that with jQuery, you'd still have the problem but no error.

Comment: This worked just fine. Thanks for your help. Not getting errors.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't close the child div. IE is rather prone to errors and will yield at you.

```
<div class="content content_green">
       <div id="comments_section"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, sorry that was actually a typo. My mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery for this:

```
$("#comments_section").parent().hide()
```

Or, you could do this the right way:

```
$("div.content.content_green").hide()
```

Currently you don't use jquery. Visit [jQuery documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page)