# Hide all divs that contain an element inside

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have three divs with same class, inside theses divs I have others divs with two different class:

```
<div class="TotalResults">
<div class="resultPassed"></div>
</div>

<div class="TotalResults">
<div class="resultPassed"></div>
</div>

<div class="TotalResults">
<div class="resultError"></div>
</div>
```

I would like to hide all divs that have `class="resultPassed"` inside him. how can I do this with javascript or jquery?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [check for child element, hide parent if child exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26725552/check-for-child-element-hide-parent-if-child-exists)

Comment: Hopefully this will help you. [Hide Parent of div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11730765/hide-parent-of-div)

Answer (score 4):

This should work :

```
$('.resultPassed').parent().hide()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it :

```
$("div").has(".resultPassed").hide();
```

Final code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    
</head>
<body> 
     <div class="TotalResults">
         <div class="resultPassed">I am resultPassed</div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="TotalResults">
        <div class="resultPassed">I am resultPassed</div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="TotalResults">
        <div class="resultError">I am not resultPassed</div>
    </div>
    
    <button class="btn">Hide</button>
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>        
    $(document).ready(function(){
        
        $(".btn").on("click",function(){
            $("div").has(".resultPassed").hide(1000);
        })
        
    })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Jquery -

`$('.resultPassed').parent().hide()` will change the display to none.

In pure JS -

```
var arr = document.getElementsByClassName("resultPassed"); 

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i].parentNode.style.display = "none";
}
```